# whenReady not setting gradle property before task runs

Tags: gradle

I have a a version property in my gradle.properties file that gives the version I am building. I have a task in the build called release that if present in the task graph will upload to the snapshot repo. However what is happening is that even though I include the release task in the build tasks, snapshot is not appended to my version property when uploadArchives runs so it attempts to upload to the wrong repository and fails. The when ready runs, but it does not seem to run before uploadArchives. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        ivy {
            credentials {
                username nexusUser
                password nexusPassword
            }
            if (version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) {
                url nexusSnapshotRepository
            } else {
                url nexusReleaseRepository
            }
        }
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph -> 
    if (!taskGraph.hasTask(release)) { 
        version = version + '-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    println "release task not included - version set to $version" 
}

task release(){
    doLast{
        println "Releasing"
    }
}
```

This is very similar to the example on the gradle site so I don't see what is going wrong.

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script is checking the `project.version` value in the configuration phase (not when the task executes), but only modifying it after the task execution graph has been built. One way to fix this is to override the repository url from inside the `taskGraph.whenReady` callback:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        ivy {
            name "nexus"
            url nexusReleaseRepository
            ...
        }
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph -> 
    if (!taskGraph.hasTask(release)) { 
        version += '-SNAPSHOT'
        uploadArchives.repositories.nexus.url nexusSnapshotRepository 
        // ps: println has to go inside here
    }
}
```